# HTML5 pattern for phone number formatting

Tags: html

```
<input type="text" pattern=" ">
```

How to make pattern to work with below formats?

### note:

- zero always the first number
- allow only number and space in between
- accept only 11 or 12 characters (include spaces)

sample:

1. 0xx xxx xxx
2. 0xx xxx xxxx

---

Many thanks :)

Comment: look at regular expressions - and tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: http://html5pattern.com/Phones should get you started

Comment: This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: pattern="0[0-9]{2} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3,4}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pattern="0[0-9]{2} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3,4}"